# Difference in Docker hyperV when connecting to a local volume vs a network volume [Windows Container]

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I am am building the an image where an external network drive is required to be mapped. There is a strange difference in the way docker interacts with the volumes, when using hyperV isolation.

**Case 1:
HyperV isolation, LocalDrive C:\data**

`docker run -v "C:\data":"C:\images" -i --isolation hyperv dockerimage`

This executes perfectly, and doesn't cause trouble. This is not an ideal situation for my use-case, as the data is present in an local network on a server.

**Case 2:
a) HyperV isolation, RemoteDrive \192.xxx.0.xx\data**

RemotePath is mapped locally to a local drive, using

`New Smb-GlobalMapping -RemotePath \\192.xxx.0.xx\data  -LocalPath H:`

Docker image is run again ,

`docker run -v "H:/":"C:/images" -i --isolation hyperv dockerimage`

Gives the following error

```
   {
        "Id": "98efda4f99108b5b55a5294f4063e0178c4eb5cb0c4c90dff892b02a7cb53784",
        "Created": "2020-11-17T16:02:00.6358887Z",
        "Path": "cmd",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "created",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 128,
            "Error": "hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 98efda4f99108b5b55a5294f4063e0178c4eb5cb0c4c90dff892b02a7cb53784: The parameter is incorrect.\n(extra info: {\"SystemType\":\"Container\",\"Name\":\"98efda4f99108b5b55a5294f4063e0178c4eb5cb0c4c90dff892b02a7cb53784\",\"Owner\":\"docker\",\"IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot\":true,\"LayerFolderPath\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\98efda4f99108b5b55a5294f4063e0178c4eb5cb0c4c90dff892b02a7cb53784\",\"Layers\":[{\"ID\":\"da562984-7fd6-595c-9fb2-dfc33bbbfc90\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\859133db54b33dbe98f51e28660da06c3a299d417841a45ed5f00c3d3b2698fa\"},{\"ID\":\"86486f96-8a0d-5098-8d22-4115528554f8\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\84f5ccf5da7976b5af2375bfdc76c65e1089ed84948278c2d3b0e6213d4cdc9d\"},{\"ID\":\"2fc30483-1251-5e25-b949-ba907b2555da\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\50faff83b3942f7551a9b0538ace20126e7345efcf2992aa5972ae8885123baa\"},{\"ID\":\"5e04bd25-484e-5d28-9f1a-f61c08d3b89d\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\b7b60b5fa26b4ad2835e8d10ceacc0c25e82c6a4f9ad296c8c11f7ecc9ab876c\"},{\"ID\":\"37385a8f-d779-5a3e-a4f1-2e10fc948496\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\5491ad561bb73035517f646a522f506a1869f9d477915348409f1a3eb2cfba19\"},{\"ID\":\"8ee96973-01f4-5a0b-9be9-82725d7e25af\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\cdd6f63701ab3d22ee79917d89a4e6c94149d5c29fa3f9db9114cd5d5c4bc264\"},{\"ID\":\"b2559eb2-1b51-5d04-a419-6d1393fbf21f\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\d9964c2a8c1a800268f9d3d6d57ed20929499698e52e01c4a0ec77eda8e76505\"},{\"ID\":\"f9e55ff6-10ae-5d1c-9146-cb04fd16dc6f\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\110665c19202b6e830ba27ba4ac9cda37da25b323c2bb4867136208b40c29e84\"},{\"ID\":\"3d845347-bfed-561e-b051-0a804df11edd\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\e428b1c7d890891419929dc40bb5d891efe69dac7e70844976cb8466bb35094a\"},{\"ID\":\"ee1dce4e-c131-53c3-bb05-7223d917aca8\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\22f70d8b8c8edd3710c1bcbc160487fb48c01a40cfb8d8b51c624947cbce42d5\"},{\"ID\":\"4b33e55b-aa1e-5574-91bc-cbdbb1857c6f\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\b47e9eb54f5da950c1c1926e5e0df0b89a8852afab06a134373057c29b151f6f\"},{\"ID\":\"37460943-6f35-510d-8eac-d1884ca7b2e4\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\8336953b188c7daad94e83b2c64ad652f1827d11818e07219a7a656010fd8efb\"},{\"ID\":\"0144cfde-366a-52d7-95cb-e872a47dc74e\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\64c264e7affc657fe876cdef72289936eb63df4f31d1d76848f5453a43182e86\"}],\"HostName\":\"98efda4f9910\",\"MappedDirectories\":[{\"HostPath\":\"h:\\\\\",\"ContainerPath\":\"c:\\\\images\",\"ReadOnly\":false,\"BandwidthMaximum\":0,\"IOPSMaximum\":0,\"CreateInUtilityVM\":false}],\"HvPartition\":true,\"EndpointList\":[\"041D1842-5520-4BD7-A5F1-1F00A6EC724E\"],\"HvRuntime\":{\"ImagePath\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\8336953b188c7daad94e83b2c64ad652f1827d11818e07219a7a656010fd8efb\\\\UtilityVM\"},\"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery\":true})",
            "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
```

**b) Process isolation ,RemoteDrive \192.xxx.0.xx\data**

`docker run -v "H:/":"C:/images" -i --isolation process dockerimage`

Runs perfectly fine.
Link to the isolation modes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container

Is this something to do permissions inside the hyperV environment?, The Error message from docker unfortunately, does not give a clear picture. Using Hyper-V isolation is necessary in my case due to compatibility issues with Windows container OS and Host OS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-20H2%2Cwindows-10-20H2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linux-style paths, e.g. instead of `"C:\images"` use `/c/images` (no quotes are necessary unless your path contains spaces).